# How to properly serialize an SSLSession?

Tags: java, ssl, https, http-caching

Let's say I want to save some HTTP response for the purpose of caching (into disk or memory). The response has an optional `SSLSession` property that is only present if the client initiated an HTTPS connection. Of course, I want the response to be recoverable which means the `SSLSession` must somehow be serialized in a recoverable manner. The `SSLSession` (or `ExtendedSSLSession`) is not `Serializable` so this leaves Java serialization out of the equation. I'm guessing one could come up with a custom format as most properties have a byte representation (e.g. certificates, primitive properties) but there are some complex fields I'm not sure how to approach (e.g. `SSLSessionContext`). So how do I properly achieve this?

Comment: I think you go the wrong way. If you want to cache a HTTP response then cache the plain HTTP header and body, i.e. with SSL removed. That's what browsers do too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Don't you think this breaks consistency of `HttpResponse::sslSession` API? (which is empty only if not originated from an HTTPS response). I think caching should be seamless to the user. I didn't know that browsers omit SSL stuff but I've checked OkHttp and it seems to cache certificates (but not through a full `SSLSession` though).

Comment: *" ...  it seems to cache certificates ..."* - likely not. I think what you see is not "certificate caching" but TLS session reuse. Session reuse is about having a faster TLS handshake (no certificates send, less roundtrips), content caching is instead about storing content locally based on caching information and next time either using the cached content directly or doing a conditional HTTP request to ask for updated content only.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Maybe I got it wrong but [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/6aae409a3e5eae0dfe0d80a40e18bfada74461b4/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/Cache.kt#L588) OkHttp's cache seems to write the encoded form of peer/local certificates of the handshake.

Comment: This seem to be stored as additional information only, i.e. like the time needed send the request and fetch the response which are also stored in the same place. Also note that the actual payload content (i.e. HTTP header and body) is stored in plain, i.e. no serialized SSLSession needed to read it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I think I want to accomplish the same: storing plain headers/body, store the `SSLSession` as an additional property, for if the request is HTTPS the client may expect it regardless of where the response came from.

Comment: *" for if the request is HTTPS the client may expect it regardless of where the response came from."* - I have no idea what you are trying to say here. Anyway, if the response is cached in plain neither the certificate, nor the execution time and nor the original SSL session are needed to provide the answer from the cache.